# Items not showing in the ActionBar with showAsAction=“always”

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to Android programming and currently trying to get the Actionbar working. My problem is, that although I set an item in the XML file to "always", it constantly ends up in the overflow menu no matter what I try. I found several similar problems on here, but none of the solutions fixed the problem.

Additional info: The ic_action_search icons are in the drawable folders of the project.

main_activity_actions.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!-- Search, always displayed -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      app:showAsAction="always" />


<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
  <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
  <string name="button_send">Send</string>
  <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
  <string name="action_search">Search</string>
  <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
  <string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>
  <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
</resources>
```

In MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

try `android:showAsAction` instead of `app:showAsAction`. Or if you're using the `appcompat_v7` backport, use both `android:showAsAction` and `app:showAsAction`(Thanks to Commonsware).

Comment: Or, if you are using the `appcompat_v7` action bar backport, you need both `android:showAsAction` *and* `app:showAsAction`.

Comment: Changed it to     android:showAsAction, the item is still in the overflow menu.

Comment: I have been looking to solve this problem from last 1 day. Thanks for answer.

Comment: If you have both of them present and you are using Android Studio, it displays an error message in the XML editor (although the app can be run and it works properly).  To get rid of the error indicator, add the following to the layout XML:  `tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"`.

Comment: here in my case I used both but still not showing it up?

Comment: I used it like `<item
        android:id="@+id/action_mark_as_read"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_all_black_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Mark as read"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />`