# Add menu item text & text in titlecase toolbar android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin

I use this code and i want to add action1 and action2 like picture & color change of this text

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />
```

menu

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item android:id="@+id/ok" android:text="action1" app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item android:id="@+id/cancel" android:text="action2"  app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    </menu>
```

my style

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">   
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>   
     <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. --> 
  </style>
```

my toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/theme_color"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

[image]

Comment: don't provide icons to menuItems

Comment: use app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: @kevz menu come in toolbar but text not appear

Comment: even after you set app:showAsAction="always"?

Comment: i used always item come on screen but text not visible

Comment: @Kishan - You need to use set title and not text, check my answer.

Comment: @kevz i add style and toolbar xml  please give your solution using style

Comment: @Kishan: Hang on buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below menu file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/ok" app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Action1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/cancel" app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Action2" />
</menu>
```

You need to set `android:title="action2"`.

Comment: i think issue in my menu item text color so can you give link for change color of menu item

Comment: I write androd:title="Action" and it appear like 'ACTION' and i want that it appear as 'Action'

Comment: @Kishan: plz post ur styles.xml

Comment: @Kishan: wts the minimum sdk ?

Comment: @kvz minimum android version is Override-Android 2.3 (Api level 10)

Comment: @Kishan: My bad I couldn't figure it out a solution yet. I'll let u know after I get 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `AppCompat_v7` action bar backport, you'll need to use both:

`android:showAsAction` and `app:showAsAction` as `always`.

Check this link: [Items not showing in the ActionBar with showAsAction=“always”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230939/items-not-showing-in-the-actionbar-with-showasaction-always)

And you need to use `setTitle` and not name like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Action1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Action2" />
</menu>
```

**Then, Here is the result:**

[image]

Comment: That's an another issue, please use ask question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set android:title property rather than  android:text for the declared menu items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/ok" android:title="action1" app:showAsAction="" />
    <item android:id="@+id/cancel" android:title="action2"  app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing text color, try this, I have not tested but it should work:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:itemTextColor="your color"
        app:menu="@menu/your menu file" />
```

Answer (score 0):

for just menu item text in title case  you can add code in your xml file

```
  <bool name="abc_config_actionMenuItemAllCaps">false</bool>
```